# Match N patterns in a bash regex

Tags: bash

I know that I can do things like:

```
[[ $s =~ ^(re)(re)$ ]]
```

to populate the `BASH_REMATCH` array with a series of bracket expression matches. But it is possible to match an *unknown number* of these matches?  For example, I get the following:

```
s='abc defghi     jklm    nop '
[[ $s =~ ^([^ ]+ +)+$ ]]
declare -p BASH_REMATCH
```

Output:

```
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH=([0]="abc defghi     jklm    nop " [1]="nop ")
```

I gather that the bracketed expression is being rewritten onto `BASH_REMATCH[1]` each time it is matched.

What I'd really like to see is:

```
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH=([0]="abc defghi     jklm    nop " 
                          [1]="abc " 
                          [2]="defghi     " 
                          [3]="jklm    " 
                          [4]="nop ")
```

Is this possible in a single command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be nice, but I don't think what you're asking for is possible for an unknown number of subexpressions.

A loop like the following might be your best bet:

```bash
s='abc defghi     jklm    nop '
a=()
t="$s"

while [[ $t =~ ^([^ ]+ +) ]]; do 
    a+=( "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" )
    t="${t#${BASH_REMATCH[1]}}" 
done

declare -p a
```

Output:

```bash
declare -a a=([0]="abc " [1]="defghi     " [2]="jklm    " [3]="nop ")
```

Without harming your original string, this strips the pattern from the start of the string, then adds the pattern to a result array and uses Pattern Expansion to strip the match from the beginning of the copy of the string. You could of course put it in a function if you wanted it to be more elegant; remember that an array can't be returned from a function, you'll need to use a global array, or a reference:

```bash
function ssplit() {
    local -n a="$1"
    local t="$2"
    while [[ $t =~ ^([^ ]+ +) ]]; do 
        a+=( "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" )
        t="${t#${BASH_REMATCH[1]}}"
    done
}

declare -a foo=()

ssplit foo "$s"

declare -p foo
```

Output:

```bash
declare -a foo=([0]="abc " [1]="defghi     " [2]="jklm    " [3]="nop ")
```

Note that `local -n` is a feature that was introduced with bash version 4.

Another possibility might be to build a match regex based on analysis of the string:

```bash
x=( $s )
printf -v pat '%s' $(printf '%.0s([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+)' $(seq 1 "${#x[@]}"))
[[ $s =~ $pat ]] && declare -p BASH_REMATCH
```

Output:

```bash
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH=([0]="abc defghi     jklm    nop " [1]="abc " [2]="defghi     " [3]="jklm    " [4]="nop ")
```

I'm not really fond of code that writes code, but this appears to work. And while it's not a single command, at least it avoids the while loop. Note that under the hood, bash is still looping through arguments to `printf` in order to build `$pat`.

Comment: Dang. I love the function, and I will use it. Your non-loop option though... That's just nuts.  Is `seq` the best way to go with this? Is it installed everywhere that `bash` is?

Comment: Heh, good catch. No, it's not. `seq` is part of Linux's "coreutils, but it's not a POSIX tool. It was added to FreeBSD as of version 9.0, and I'm not sure when it was added to Mac OS X. On BSD platforms, [`jot`](http://man.freebsd.org/jot) is usually king. Of course, on platforms with neither of these tools, [`awk` will do](https://superuser.com/a/600684/113356).